# How can I change MAC address of VLAN interface in macOS?

Tags: macos, network, ethernet

I'm setting up a `vlan` interface using Ethernet.

The `vlan` interface's parent interface is `en5`:

```
vlan0: flags=8843<UP, BROADCAST, RUNNING, SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
options=6063<RXCSUM, TXCSUM, TS04, TSO6, PARTIAL_SUM, ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
ether 00:e0:4c:68:33:10
inet6 fe80::1079:2168:44d9: 262a%vlan0 prefixlen 64 secured scoped 0x15
net 169.254.22.248 netmask oxffff000 broadcast 169.254.255.255
nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD, DAD>
vlan: 129 parent interface: en5
media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
status: active
```

I would like to change the MAC address of the `vlan` interface, but `ifconfig` fails with this error:

```
sudo ifconfig vlan0 ether 02:00:00:00:06:00
ifconfig: ioctl (SIOCAIFADDR): Operation not supported on socket
```

I tried changing the MAC address of the parent interface (`en5`), but I get this error:

```
 ifconfig: ioctl (SIOCAIFADDR): Can't assign requested address
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

If I do this on a Linux operating system, everything is fine:

```
$ sudo ip link add link eth0 name eth0.1 type vlan id 89
$ sudo ip addr add 192.168.0.121/24 dev eth0.1
$ sudo ip link set dev eth0.1 address 88:00:00:00:00:00
$ sudo ip link set eth0.1 up
```

Mac OS Ethernet interface VLAN Setting.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. From reading `man ifconfig`, a `vlan` interface must be associated with a physical interface and the `vlan interface is assigned a copy of the parent interface's flags and the parent's ethernet address`, so it seems the MAC address is not configurable, which explains the error message you get. Which command do you use to change the MAC address of `en5`?